# How can I handle UsernameNotFoundException?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I've been using some previous examples of testing methods some of my work partners used and they didn't have any problem but when i use them for this project it doesn't work at all. One of my partners saw the methods and he didn't know either what was wrong.
This is my test class:

```
    @Mock
    UserRepository dataRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    protected UserService userService;
    
    private User u;
    

    @BeforeEach()
    void setUp() {
        u = new User();
        u.setId(23L);
        u.setUsername("test");
        u.setPassword("Pass1234.");
        u.setInfo(null);
        this.dataRepository.save(u);
    }
    
    @Test
    void testLoadUserByUsername() throws Exception {
        when(dataRepository.findByUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(u);
        userService.loadUserByUsername("test");
        assertEquals(u, userService.loadUserByUsername(anyString()));
        verify(dataRepository).findByUsername(anyString());


}
        
    @Test
    void testFindAllUsers() throws Exception {
        List<User> user = this.userService.findAllUsers();
        Assertions.assertNotNull(user);
    
}

}
```

When i execute the test i get the same trace every time and it is, for the **first method**:

```
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User can't be found
    at com.project.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:41)
```

I don't know what could it be because i'm searching the same name i'm setting just a few lines above so if u could help me i would appreciate it.

The UserService class is:

```
@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder               passw;

@Autowired
private UserRepository                  userRepository;

@Autowired
private DataRepository  dataRepository;


@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User can't be found");
    }

    return user;
}


public List<User> findAllUsers() {

    List<User> l = new ArrayList<User>();
    l = (List<User>) this.userRepository.findAll();

    return l;
}


public void save(final User u) {
    this.userRepository.save(u);
}
```

}

And the line of the code that is pointed by the exception is:

```
userService.loadUserByUsername("test");
```

Thank u so much.

Comment: You will need to debug your test and code to find out why it raises the exception. If after debugging you still need help, [edit] your question to include the code for `UserService`, especially its `loadUserByUsername()` method. See [mcve] for more suggestions on creating a good code example.

Comment: i edited and added the class, thank u @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Now it's time to debug your code. `user` is `null` for some reason. Dig the next layer deeper and see what `UserRepository.findByUsername()` does and why its returning null.

Comment: You have mock repository object and you are calling save on it in before each method, your assumption is that will save the object in db and service will be able to load it, but it will not you are getting null from the repository, hence the if condition passing throwing exception.

Comment: findByUsername finds the user with the username i give it, that's why i don't understand it returns null @code_mechanic

Comment: Is this integration test or unit test? You should use `@MockBean` instead of  `@Mock` if you initiating whole spring context of your app, please post full test class here and also, didn't get the logic of saving the user in `@BeforeEach` and then mocking the behaviour in real test.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your `@Mock`. Basically, you are mocking an object in your test class and then pretending the `@Autowired` object in your `UserService` class to be mocked. What you are missing here is the instruction that tells Spring to put your mocked object into your `UserService class`. So here is the upgrade that will fix it.

Your test class becomes like this:

```
@Mock
UserRepository dataRepository;

@InjectMocks
@Autowired
protected UserService userService;

private User u;


@BeforeEach()
void setUp() {
    u = new User();
    u.setId(23L);
    u.setUsername("test");
    u.setPassword("Pass1234.");
    u.setInfo(null);
    this.dataRepository.save(u);
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

// Here goes the remaining code as it is...
```

Basically what I did was to add the `@InjectMocks` annotation above the `@Autowired` element that needs to receive your mock. Furthermore, with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` I have initialized the mocks.

NOTE: the line where you do `this.dataRepository.save(u);` is useless. The point is that every method you call on a Mocked object is not executed, therefore there is no difference  in having it or not. The only meaningful line is `when(dataRepository.findByUsername(anyString())).thenReturn(u);` that you have below.

PS. The dependency that contains `@InjectMocks` and `MockitoAnnotations` is the following:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Wish you a great day,

D